# how do I open a keystore file to view sha1 key?

Tags: android, visual-studio, keystore, sha1

how do I open a `debug.keystore` file to view `sha1` key?

i found a command but what i can tell is that this is creating a new keystore file. I don't want to re-create another keystore file of same project. I just want to open it and view `sha1` key

```
 keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: `keytool -list` lists the entries in a keystore. It does not create a keystore, nor does it create a key in a keystore.

Comment: i tried this in CMD and visual studio but its say `keytool` command not found. which tool are you using?

Comment: is it `keytool.exe -list`?

Comment: I am using `keytool`. You can find it in your JDK's `bin` directory, the same directory that the `javac` compiler resides.

Comment: right i had to to be in jdk bin folder. ok got it thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command to view your ssh1 fingerprint


**keytool -list -v -keystore "path_of_your_keystor_file/debug.keystore"**